# AFImageRequestOperation in order not asynchronous

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am implementing a code that downloads images and saves them in the database of the app,

I have an array of objects, each object contains the image url and some other information. To Download the images I'm using the class library AFImageRequestOperation.h AFNetworking.

My code downloads and saves the data in the database, but need to notify the user which image is downloaded, eg: if I have an array containing 5 objects (quoted just above what each object), will have to do downloading the same order that is in the array, but as AFImageRequestOperation makes downloading asynchronously item 4 can be downloaded before the first item.

In short, I want to have control and only release for the next download when the previous one is completed.

I have a for that runs through the array of objects and calls a function for each position, the function has the following code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrImagem valueForKey:@"urlimagem"]]];
    AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request imageProcessingBlock:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){

        Imagens *imagem = (Imagens *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"IMAGENS" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        // Save Image
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
        [imagem setCategoria:cat];
        [imagem setTitulo:[arrImagem valueForKey:@"titulo"]];
        [imagem setDescricao:[arrImagem valueForKey:@"descricao"]];
        [imagem setImagem:imageData];



        NSError *error;
        if(![managedObjectContext save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"houve um erro muito grave");
            //return false;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Salvou imagem");
        }

    }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

    }];

    [operation start];
```

I do not know if my question was very clear, but basically my question is similar to this [link](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&tl=pt&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853046/download-images-in-order-with-afnetworking&usg=ALkJrhi-Vx_gSuKfVIIpnTiLmH_ix0uCnQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to solve my problem, sorry for the delay in posting the solution, follow the code below:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

        dispatch_group_enter(group);

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];

        AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request imageProcessingBlock:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){

            //your implementation        

            dispatch_group_leave(group);     //<== NOTICE THIS

        }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
           //your implementation

            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

        }];

        [operation start];

        dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Thus the downloads ocorerão in order, if this code is inside a case, the next download will only be called when the method success^:  or failure^: is called

Answer (score 0):

AFImageRequestOperation is a subclass of NSOperation so you can use:

```
- (void) addDependency: (NSOperation*) operation
```

to make sure that one operation finishes before the other.

For example:

```
NSOperation *op1 = [[NSOperation alloc]init];
NSOperation *op2 = [[NSOperation alloc]init];

[op1 addDependency: op2];
```

This way **op1** won't start before **op2** is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in your class where you call the download code and add a block as parameter which receives the downloaded UIImage, the image url (and other infos that you need) or you can implement a delegate with the same params from the block. It can lock something like:

```
-(void)downloadImageWithSuccess:(void (^)(UIImage *image, NSString *url, OtherParms here))success 
                       failure:(void (^)(NSError *error)failure {
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrImagem valueForKey:@"urlimagem"]]];

    AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request imageProcessingBlock:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
        Imagens *imagem = (Imagens *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"IMAGENS" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        // Save Image
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
        [imagem setCategoria:cat];
        [imagem setTitulo:[arrImagem valueForKey:@"titulo"]];
        [imagem setDescricao:[arrImagem valueForKey:@"descricao"]];
        [imagem setImagem:imageData];

        NSError *error;
        if(![managedObjectContext save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"houve um erro muito grave");
            //return false;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Salvou imagem");
        }
      success(imagem, [request.URL absoluteString], otherParams);

    }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        failure(error);

    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

}

And when you call the method from your code you can do something like(using blocks):

```
[catalog downloadImageWithSuccess:^(UIImage *image, NSString *url, OtherParms here) {
                //NOTIFY USER THAT THE IMAGE WITH URL HAS BEEN DOWNLOADED
            }
            failure:^(NSError *error) {
                //NTOFIY USER THAT THE IMAGE FAILED
            }

];
```

Comment: Okay, I tried to implement your code, put it inside the block does not recognize the parameters passed, if I put these parameters eg (void (^)(UIImage *image, NSString *url ...  Within the scope of the function can not access-them. understood what you meant?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you can't access :D. In which metod you can't access the parameters ?